# FreeTDS with UTF-8 doesn't return UTF-8 symbols

Tags: php, utf-8, freetds

I am making a MSSQL query using FreeTDS. The problem is that I don't get any special UTF-8 symbols. I am using an PHP application and I have odbc.ini files with the following configuration:

```
[test]

host = server.com

port = xxxxx

tds version = 7.4

client charset = WINDOWS-1257
```

I also tried client charset UTF-8. but it didn't helped. What could be the problem?

Comment: What encoding are your tables in?

Comment: It's WINDOWS-1257 @DarkBee

Comment: You have to make sure your tables, your connection and the content-type are all set to `UTF-8` to make sure the characters are shown proper

Comment: I can't change the tables content-type. I just connected to the database and it's collation is "SQL_Lithuanian_CP1257_CI_AS" so I suppose it's a WINDOWS-1257 type. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the version to 7.2 solved the problem.

Comment: Version 7.4 is only support in FreeTDS 1.0 and greater. Most Linux distros still install FreeTDS 0.91 or 0.95 via package managers.